# Splitting a cookie string and saving the split cookie value in a external csv file in Apache JMeter Selenium Webdriver Sampler

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Objective : I wanna "split" the extracted cookie from ";" and save the cookie value in a iterative manner for each user in a csv file, column wise, for my Apache JMeter code in **Selenium Webdriver Sampler** in **java** language.
I am using a **CSV Dataset config** to fetch the **username** & **password** and would like to save the cookie value in a separate column.

**I am unable to spilt the cookie and save using the following code snippet.**

My code Snippet

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.String;

// Login 
String title = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(title);
Assert.assertEquals("Sign in to your account", title);
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys(new String[] {WDS.vars.get("username")});
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(new String[] {WDS.vars.get("password")});
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='button']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);

// Generating the cookie
String rawValue = driver.manage().getCookieNamed(".sampleCookie");
System.out.println(rawValue);
WDS.log.info(WDS.vars.get("rawValue"));
System.out.println("Login Successful");
WDS.log.info("Login Successful");
```

> I am able to use the above code snippet to generate the cookie, but unable to print in JMeter Log console using
> **WDS.log.info(WDS.vars.get("rawValue"));**
>
> Info:  2023-02-03 14:34:08,656 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: null

**I am unable to split the cookie via below mentioned code.**

```
//Splitting the cookie 

//Split cookie string from semicolon
String[] cookie = rawValue.split(";");
```

> Error:
> 2023-02-03 15:38:44,557 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method split( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.Cookie' : at Line: 53 : in file: inline evaluation of:` import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : rawValue.split ( ";" )
> in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

**I am unable to save the split cookie value or the raw cookie Value in that case via below mentioned code.**

```
//Write the cookie value to a csv file

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Scripts\\TestData\\Cookie.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(WDS.vars.get("rawValue"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

> Error: 2023-02-03 15:45:13,652 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler:
> Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : Method Invocation out.write : at Line: 54 : in file: inline evaluation of:` import org.openqa.selenium.*; import
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : out .write (
> WDS .vars .get ( "rawValue" ) )
>
> Target exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "String.length()" because "str" is null  in inline evaluation of:
> ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import
> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

I have imported the required classes and have tried executing this code snippets individually with the login code, did'nt worked out.
I would really appreciate if anyone can aid me with the solutions.

```
raw cookie Value = .sampleCookie=eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6IjEiLCJoyA;

split cookie value = eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6IjEiLCJoyA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.manage().getCookieNamed` function gives you an instance of [org.openqa.selenium.Cookie](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html) which doesn't have `split()` function

If you want to continue with this approach you need to cast it to [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) first:

```
String[] cookie = rawValue.toString().split(";");
```

Alternatively you can use Cookie class functions instead of "splitting", i.e.

- `rawValue.getName()`
- `rawValue.getValue()`
- `rawValue.getDomain()`
- `rawValue.getExpiry()`
- `rawValue.isSecure()`
- `rawValue.isHttpOnly()`

The same is for printing it to the log file, you cannot put a Cookie object there, you need to change it to be a String:

`WDS.log.info(rawValue.toString());`

Also your approach of writing the variables into the file won't work if you intend to run your script with 2 or more users, the target file will have corrupt data due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so consider switching to [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) instead.

Comment: Thank You much for aiding me out ! The two issues from top to bottom are resolved, but am unable to save the extracted "rawValue" or any value of the cookie in external csv file using SampleVariables and Flexible File Writer.
It gives me the below waring
WARN k.a.j.r.FlexibleFileWriter: variable#0 does not exist!

I have also added the Sample Variables  in user. properties file 
sample_variables=rawValue

Comment: I fail to see where do you give the value to this variable, I believe you need to have something like `WDS.vars.put("rawValue", rawValue.toString())` somewhere in your script. `WDS.vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information on this and other shorthands

Comment: Thank You @Dmitri T.
This worked : WDS.vars.put("rawValue", rawValue.toString())